# Как отследить разрыв кабеля в TCP соединении?

Tags: tcp, c++

Здравствуйте! Каким образом можно отследить разрыв TCP соединения? Можно отправлять некое спец сообщение и ждать ответ... и если не дождались, то определять как разрыв... Но это как-то не очень. Есть более простой способ определения разрыва соединения со стороны севера и клиента?

Comment: только пинги. То есть, вопрос-ответ.

Либо напрямую обращаться к сетевой карте.

Comment: пинги не всегда отрабатываются сервером - скажем если стоит запрет на ответы к пингам

Comment: Надежно, только своим прикладным протоколом (со своими таймаутами).

Я так понимаю, что стандартные 1.5 часа Вас не устраивают.

@KoVadim,  под 

    напрямую обращаться к сетевой карте

Вы имели в виду определить, есть ли несущая? А чужая обычная карта ни на один пакет отвечать не станет.

Comment: Пинги -- это вы о чём? ICMP или небольшие пакетики туда-сюда по tcp-соединению?
@KoVadim а если соединение оборвано далеко от Вашей карты?

@Alerr Вы о чём? Разрыв tcp-соединения -- это одно. Обрыв кабеля где-то на маршруте -- это другое. Так о чём Вы беспокоитесь?

Comment: Я беспокоюсь о физическом обрыве кабеля... Слать и ловить пакеты, сообщающие о присутствии пользователя в сети-это как-то не очень... TCP, это же "надежный" протокол, разве он не уведомит об обрыве кабеля?

Comment: @Alerr, уведомит. Стандартно через 1.5 часа. 

В том-то и надежность TCP, что временные неполадки не влияют на обмен данными на прикладном уровне. Система прячет их от Вас.

Comment: А уведомит и сервер и клиент? 1.5 часа это не дело((( Можно это время уменьшить?

Comment: обычно протоколы уровнем выше используют keepalive, т.е. клиент посылает сообщения серверу раз в n времени, и сервер клиенту тоже, такой-же способ используют разведчики и драгдилеры (не позвоню - убей их всех)

Comment: @Alerr, да и клиент и сервер. 

Вот вопросом, как менять таймауты в TCP и озаботьтесь. Сходу не помню, очевидно его можно менять (но IMHO для всех сразу), а вот в какой момент на какие соединения это изменеие повлияет - не помню.

Ищите.

Comment: И на том спасибо)

Comment: убило "убей их всех" :)

Comment: @Alerr "1.5 часа это не дело((( " А если через час обрыв починят? А у Вас уже программа сказала "Гуд бай"?

Comment: @alexlz: Смотря для какой программы. Если у неё, например, военное применение, за полтора часа могут произойти изменения на политической карте.

Comment: под "пингами" я имел ввиду часть протокола. То есть специальный пакет, на который сервер должен прислать ответ как можно скорее.

>> а если соединение оборвано далеко от Вашей карты?

а нужно ещё и в метрах расстояние до обрыва получать?
По факту - если есть обрыв возле нас, то сетевая карта точно его знает (лампочка то перестала гореть), но если после роутера... тут ситуация неоднозначная.

Comment: Искал, что-то не могу найти где это в TCP можно изменить это время... Нашел пример на сайте, который постоянно, в течении какого-то времени кидает сообщения...

Comment: @Alerr, откровенно, сейчас неохота копаться в этой теме. Попробуйте начать с поиска RFC по TCP и дальше отталкивайтесь от них.

Но, (насколько помню) изменить таймаут можно только для всех соединений данного узла скопом. Скорее всего этот параметр доступен через /sys (в линуксе). Возможно, вообще, придется где-нибудь ядро потрогать. 

Скорее всего остальные пользователи сервера не примут такого решения одного из них. Поэтому идея (в общем случае) не слишком хорошая.

Comment: @Alerr @avp действительно, трогать эти параметры (как и кип элайв, и всяческие размеры мту) сильно не рекомендующийся. Используйте пульсации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На уровне сетевых протоколов самый верный способ, как уже советовали в комментах, реализация т.н. "пульсаций" или "пингов" в протоколе верхнего уровня (своего). Настоятельно рекоммендую почитать Йозефа Снайдера - Эффективное программирование TCP/IP, в первых советах доходчиво описано что есть надежность TCP.
Остальные способы через чур узконаправленные и ограниченны чтобы иметь право на жизнь.