# TCP Winsocks Выбор оптимального размера буфера отправки

Tags: c++, windows, сеть, winsock2

Часто возникает обрыв соединения TCP, использую потоковый сокет. Отправляю данные сегментами по 128 КБ. Может ли проблема быть связана с размером буфера отправки? Речь идет не о буфере отправки сокета, а о буфере, который передается в функцию `send`.

Какие в целом бывают распространные причины обрыва соединения TCP, если хосты не закрывают соединение и регулярно обмениваются данными? У меня так же настроена опция keep-alive у обоих хостов (может следовало настроить лишь у одного?) - раз в 30 секунд отправляется пакет для проверки соединения.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/202315/481134

Comment: Самая распространенная причина - криво написанная программа. Приводите [mcve].

Comment: [Проблема XY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY_(%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0))